# Expected value of shifted gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

If x is a random gaussian noise, how can I derive the value of
$$ E[x(n-a)x(n-b)]$$
$$\text{where } x(n)=\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$$

Also what if x(n) has zero mean?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is $x(n-a)$ distributed as? Essentially, assuming they're still gaussian, how do $\sigma$ and $\mu$ depend on the argument? Or did you intend to ask about a gaussian process instead? (Even in the latter case, information is required about the autocorrelation).

Comment: yes indeed ... x is an uncorrelated gaussian noise, so shifted values should also follow normal distribution. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There should not be any correlation as x is a random noise. So x(n) and x(n-a) should not have any correlation

Comment: question updated

Comment: Okay, so you may write $X(n) = \mu + Y(n)$, where $Y$ is a white noise with variance $\sigma^2$. Consequently, $\mathbb{E}[X(t)X(s)] = \mu^2 + \sigma^2 \delta(t -s)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... this is the answer i have, but I am finding little tough to derive it. Can you please elaborate the steps? Also, if you write as answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: Recall that correlation is $R(t,s):= \mathbb{E}[X(t)X(s)] - \mathbb{E}[X(t)]\mathbb{E}[X(s)]$. By definition, correlation for an uncorrelated process is $0$ when $t \neq s$, and $\sigma^2$ when $t = s$. This is the same as writing $R(t,s) = \sigma^2\delta(t - s)$. A little bit of rearrangement should get you the answer.

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot :)